# How can i get a select list in MVC without hardcoding properties

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities

The following works as it should. The problem is that i do not want to hardcode the `AvailabilityID` and the `AvailabilityName`

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  SelectList AvailabilityList = new SelectList(db.Availabilities, "AvailabilityID", "AvailabilityName");
  ViewBag.AvailabilityList = AvailabilityList;
  return View();
}
```

and here comes the view

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Availability, (SelectList)ViewBag.AvailabilityList, new
                                {
                                    @class = "red",
                                    data_placeholder = "please choose"
                                })
```

How should i modify the code above?
I am 99% sure with a lambda expression, so i can also add an order by clause... but what about the other 1% ?

Thank you

Comment: You have to hard code it (the `SelectList` constructor takes `string` as the 2nd and 3rd arguments. Why not use `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Actually i want to remove the 2nd and 3rd arguments, but if i do this, the "whole objext" is displayed in the view. I will try the IEnumerable<SelectListItem> thing

Comment: `db.Availabilities.OrderBy(...).Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Value = x.AvailabilityID.ToString(), Text = x.AvailabilityName };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little extension (in a static class) like this could do the trick

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectListItem<T, TValue, TText>(
            this IEnumerable<T> enumerable,
            Func<T, TText> text,
            Func<T, TValue> value,
            )
        {
            return enumerable.Select(item => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = text(item).ToString(),
                Value = value(item).ToString(),
            }).AsEnumerable();
```

usage :

```
//you can add an OrderBy if needed
var AvailabilityList = db.Availabilities.ToList().ToSelectListItem(m => m.AvailabilityName, m => m.AvailabilityId);
```

of course, it's an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` now, not a `SelectList`, but both can be used with a `DropDownListFor`

Comment: Thank you sir.  I now get the following error in the view Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectListIterator`2[...Availability,System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem]' to type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList'. What am i doing terribly wrong here?

Comment: Just change in your view : `(SelectList)ViewBag.AvailabilityList` to `(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.AvailabilityList`

Comment: is'nt that we are still hardcoding? difference is they are not string now